# User System - Multiple Roles in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

So I am in the process of attempting to create a basic user system and within this system I want users to be able to have multiple roles.

Say for example I have the roles as follows: Administrator, Events Organiser, Donator

What is the best way to assign these multiple roles to a user and then check if they have any of these roles for showing certain permissions.

If it was only one role per person then it wouldn't be a problem as I'd just assign say Administrator = 10, Organiser = 5 and Donator = 1 and then do an if statement to check if the MySQL data is equal to any of those three numbers.

I can't imagine there is a way to add a MySQL Field and fill it with say "Administrator,Donator" and therefore that user would have both of those roles?

Is it just a case of I would need to create 3 separate fields and put a 0 or a 1 in those fields and check each one separately?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use multiple tables and join them:

```
User
--------------
id    name
 1    test

Role
--------------
id    name
 1    Donator
 2    Organizer
 3    Administrator

User_Role
--------------
id    user_id    role_id
 1    1          1
 2    1          3


SELECT * FROM User u 
    LEFT JOIN User_Role ur ON u.id = ur.user_id
    LEFT JOIN Role r ON ur.role_id = r.id
WHERE r.name = "Administrator";
```

The query is easier if you know you only have 3 roles and they are easy to remember.

```
SELECT * FROM User u LEFT JOIN User_Role ur ON u.id = ur.user_id WHERE ur.role_id = 3;
```

Comment: Ok, so I now have it so that I can get the role IDs displaying in an array for a certain user with the query:

SELECT role_id FROM wp_users u LEFT JOIN users_roles ur ON u.id = ur.user_id WHERE u.id ='$user_ID'

How would I make it though so it showed the role name instead of the role_id.

Comment: **SELECT role.name AS name FROM wp_users u LEFT JOIN users_roles ur ON u.id = ur.user_id LEFT JOIN role r ON ur.role_id = r.id WHERE u.id = '$user_ID'** - you should look into parameterized queries as well.

Answer (score 7):

You will have a **roles**, **users** and **users_roles** tables:

The `roles` table will hold the various roles your users can have. In my example data I've declared Administrator and Donator roles.

```
roles
    id             unsigned int(P)
    description    varchar(15)

+----+---------------+
| id | description   |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | Administrator |
|  2 | Donator       |
| .. | ............. |
+----+---------------+
```

And of course you'll have to store information about your users.

```
users
    id          unsigned int(P)
    username    varchar(32)
    password    varbinary(255)
    etc.

+----+----------+----------+-----+
| id | username | password | ... |
+----+----------+----------+-----+
|  1 | bob      | ******** | ... |
|  2 | mary     | ******** | ... |
| .. | ........ | ........ | ... |
+----+----------+----------+-----+
```

Finally you'll tie the two together in the `users_roles` table. In my example data you can see that `bob` is a Donator and `mary` is both an Administrator and a Donator. The `user_id` and `role_id` are both foreign keys to their respective tables and together they form the primary key for this table.

```
users_roles
    user_id    unsigned int(F user.id)\_(P)
    role_id    unsigned int(F role.id)/

+----+---------+---------+
| id | user_id | role_id |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 |       1 |       2 |
|  2 |       2 |       1 |
|  3 |       2 |       2 |
| .. | ....... | ....... |
+----+---------+---------+
```

This way a user can have an unlimited number of roles.

Comment: hah - you win for including data types and indexes/foreign keys.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to create two new table for such small thing. 
You can utilize MySQL built in **SET data type** or you can store comma separated role in varchar and do query operation using **FIND_IN_SET()**
Eg.

`SELECT * FROM user WHERE FIND_IN_SET('admin', role)>0;`

`+----+----------+----------+----------------+
| id | username | password | role (varchar)  |
+----+----------+----------+-----------------+
|  1 | bob      | ******** | admin           |
|  2 | mary     | ******** | admin,role1     |
| .. | ........ | ........ | role1,role2     |
+----+----------+----------+-----------------+`