# Role Based DB table Design

Tags: database

I'm have a requirment consisting of  7 roles in my database, each role has different attributes and want to maintain a single login table with username, password and role. So, is it a good practice to maintain a same login table for group of roles and saving all the other related details of the each role in a separate table based on their roles.

Comment: So, is it a good practice to maintain a same login table for group of roles and saving all the other related details of the each role in a separate table based on their roles.

Comment: Here's a [basic design you could use as a foundation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980101/user-system-multiple-roles-in-mysql-database/12980205#12980205).

Comment: Thanks for the link Benny. It helped me to understand the design but I have different attributes for each role. How do you want me to maintain this records of each roles? Do you want me to maintain each role in a different table with all their details and create a reference of the login table.

Comment: If they are truly just attributes of a Role then you just need to add columns to the `role` table. If they are more than just attributes you need to edit your question and provide more information.